# How to check if an object has been instantiated within button handler

Tags: c#, if-statement, button, onclick, instantiation

I am making a calculator app that creates an object in the button click event.  This calculator uses an object that stores a running total as a property then adds the new number from the textbox to that property.  **Unfortunately every time the button gets clicked it makes a new object so I do not have a constant running total.**  I tried `if (object == null)` but to do that I have to set the object to null in the button event so it will always be null. According to my assignment the object has to be instantiated within the click event.

```
public class Calculator
{
    public double Total  = 0.0;   // Running total for calculator

    public double Addition(double number)
    {
        Total += number;
        return Total;
    }

    public double Subtraction(double number)
    {
        Total -= number;
        return Total;
    }

    public double Multiplication(double number)
    {
        Total *= number;
        return Total;
    }

    public double Division(double number)
    {
        if (number != 0) // If number does not equal 0 Calculate
        {
            Total /= number;
            return Total;
        }
        Total = 0;      // If it does set the answer to 0 to avoid errors
        return Total;
    }

    public virtual void Clear()
    {
        Total = 0.0;
    }
}  

public class ScientificCalculator : Calculator
{
    public double Memory { get; set; } = 0.0;   // Running total for calculator

    public double Log(double number)
    {
        return Math.Log(number);
    }

    public double Sin(double number)
    {
        return Math.Sin(number);
    }

    public double Cos(double number)
    {
        return Math.Cos(number);
    }

    public double Tan(double number)
    {
        return Math.Tan(number);
    }

    public override void Clear()
    {
        Memory = 0.0;
    }
}

public partial class CalcQ3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScientificCalculator calc = null;
        bool isNumber = double.TryParse(txtNewNumber.Text, out double number);   // Testing if textbox value is numeric

        if (isNumber)                                                            // if numeric add number to total
        {
            if (calc == null)                                                    // if an instance has not been created creat one
            {
                calc = new ScientificCalculator();
            }

            calc.Addition(number);
            lblTotal.Text = (calc.Total).ToString();
        }
        else                                                                     // Display error
        {
            txtNewNumber.Text = string.Empty;
            txtNewNumber.Focus();
            lblTotal.Text = "Please Enter A Numeric Value";
        }
    }

    protected void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScientificCalculator calc = new ScientificCalculator();
        calc.Clear();
        lblTotal.Text = (calc.Total).ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the formatting changes, sorry this is my first time on the website

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion. You only need to make calc  as static

Please see below code

```
public partial class CalcQ3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private static ScientificCalculator calc = new ScientificCalculator();
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double number;
    bool isNumber = double.TryParse(txtNewNumber.Text, out  number);   // Testing if textbox value is numeric

    if (isNumber)                                                            // if numeric add number to total
    {


        calc.Addition(number);
        lblTotal.Text = (calc.Total).ToString();
    }
    else                                                                     // Display error
    {
        txtNewNumber.Text = string.Empty;
        txtNewNumber.Focus();
        lblTotal.Text = "Please Enter A Numeric Value";
    }
}

protected void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    calc = new ScientificCalculator();
    calc.Clear();
    lblTotal.Text = (calc.Total).ToString();
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the fast responce, should I keep everything else the same?

Comment: I get an error on the lblTotal.Text = (calc.Total).ToString();       sayings Calculator total cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead